# Decoding a fetched email header or subject into a readable manner

Tags: python, email

I get emails with unique subjects, and I want to save them.
I tried this (stage with credentials input is omitted)

```
import email
import imaplib
suka.select('Inbox')
key = 'FROM'
value = 'TBD'
_, data = suka.search(None, key, value)
mail_id_list = data[0].split()
msgs = [] 
for num in mail_id_list:
    typ, data = suka.fetch(num, '(RFC822)')
    msgs.append(data)
for msg in msgs[::-1]:
    for response_part in msg:
        if type(response_part) is tuple:
            my_msg=email.message_from_bytes((response_part[1]))
            print ("subj:", my_msg['subject'])
            
            for part in my_msg.walk():  
                #print(part.get_content_type())
                if part.get_content_type() == 'text/plain':
                    print (part.get_payload())
```

I do get the subjects, but in a form of `"subj: =?utf-8?B?0LfQsNGP0LLQutCwIDIxXzE0MTIyMg==?="`. Thus, a decoding is required. The secret seems to be, which variable needs to be decoded?
Also tried the other way:

```
yek, do = suka.uid('fetch', govno,('RFC822'))
```

, where `govno` is the latest email in the inbox. The output is "can't concat int to bytes".
Thus, is there a way to decode the subjects as they appear in the email client? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a built-in [decode_header()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.header.html#email.header.decode_header) method.

> Decode a message header value without converting the character set.
> The header value is in header.
>
> This function returns a list of (decoded_string, charset) pairs
> containing each of the decoded parts of the header. charset is None
> for non-encoded parts of the header, otherwise a lower case string
> containing the name of the character set specified in the encoded
> string.

```
>>> from email.header import decode_header
>>> decoded_headers = decode_header("=?utf-8?B?0LfQsNGP0LLQutCwIDIxXzE0MTIyMg==?=")
>>> decoded_headers
[(b'\xd0\xb7\xd0\xb0\xd1\x8f\xd0\xb2\xd0\xba\xd0\xb0 21_141222', 'utf-8')]
>>> first = decoded_headers[0]
>>> first[0].decode(first[1])
'заявка 21_141222'
```

You can `decode` the actual value returned by `decode_header` using the charset returned by it.

---

For follow-up question, here's a helper function to get the header value in case of multiline header value which handlers errors -

```
from email.header import decode_header

def get_header(header_text, default='utf8'):
    try:
        headers = decode_header(header_text)
    except:
        print('Error while decoding header, using the header without decoding')
        return header_text

    header_sections = []
    for text, charset in headers:
        try:
            # if charset does not exist, try to decode with utf-8
            header_section = text.decode(charset or 'utf-8')
        except:
            # if we fail to decode the text(header is incorrectly encoded)
            # Try to do decode, and ignore the decoding errors
            header_section = text.decode('utf-8', errors='ignore')
        if header_section:
            header_sections.append(header_section)
    return ' '.join(header_sections)

print(get_header("=?utf-8?B?0LfQsNGP0LLQutCwIDIxXzE0MTIyMg==?="))
```

Comment: dear Jay, many thanks. Variable my_msg['subject'] definetely stores all emails. Is there a way to convert it to a set of decoded values? Because in Your code (which I am buch beholden to You to) we get only 1 email ([(b'\xd0\xb7\xd0\xb0\xd1\x8f\xd0\xb2\xd0\xba\xd0\xb0 21_141222', 'utf-8'). Same goes, if we write podonock = decode_header(my_msg['subject']). The output is just single email with single subject, but will it be possible to get all of them?

Comment: Sorry, I did not get your question, can you elaborate with an example? If you have multiple header to be decoded, you can just loop through them and maybe convert my snippet into a function to get the decoded value directly. If `decode_header()` returns multiple parts, you can concatenate the decoded strings and loop through it.

Comment: if I write "msgs = [] 
for num in mail_id_list:
    typ, data = suka.fetch(num, '(RFC822)')
    msgs.append(data)"      I see all inbound messages not yet decoded. But later on "for msg in msgs[::-1]:
    for response_part in msg:
        if type(response_part) is tuple:
            my_msg=email.message_from_bytes((response_part[1]))
            padla =( my_msg['subject'])"               Output of padla variable is just one heading. Why not all emails, but just one are saved to padla variable?

Comment: Strangely enough, I do have a column with all headers. print(my_msg['subject']) accurately returns all headers, un-decoded. If I split my_msg['subject'], I get only 1 header, not a list of them.